# Delete all rows of a pandas dataframe where certain conditions are met over all columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

I want to delete ALL rows (red marked in the picture) where every column has a value like:

```
"", "nan", "NaT"
```

I tried several things like dropna, replacing and dropping, but I am can not make it work to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
mask = df.fillna('').isin(["", "nan", "NaT"])

df = df[~mask.all(axis=1)]
```